# Paypal Button manager api throwing 404 not found error on Live site

Tags: c#, paypal, paypal-nvp, paypal-soap

We have integrated Paypal "Button Manager api" for our clients in 2015,till last wednesday it was working fine but since then it has stopped working and throwing the error "404 not found".

I have already checked the token,Api username, and Password. everything seems to be fine. Can anyone please help us/guide us on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Has the URL for the button changed on PayPal's side? That would explain the 404.

Comment: Wow the Button Manager API, that's extremely old and I suppose deprecated or in minimal maintenance mode. You can contact PayPal for support on that 404, but in the meantime consider something more current based on https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/

Comment: Thank you Nick. Even I do feel the same that URL must have been changed but I am unable to find which URL it could be. I did change the return URL,Paypal Submit URL etc

Comment: Thank you Preston. Yes Button manager API is quite old and is deprecated. I guess it was deprecated over a year ago. However,it was working till last week. I am confused if I shd change the code or look for help in the exisiting code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend upgrading to the newer integration. Deprecated software tends to get more frustrating to maintain over time as less and less people use it.